# Store multi-line input into a String (Python)

Tags: python

Input:

```
359716482
867345912
413928675
398574126
546281739
172639548
984163257
621857394
735492861
```

my code :

```
print("Enter the array:\n")   
userInput = input().splitlines()
print(userInput)
```

my problem here is that, `userInput` only takes in the first line value but it doesn't
seem to take in values after the first line?

Answer (score 20):

You can use `readlines()` method of file objects:

```
import sys
userInput = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Comment: Nice. For the record: this will require doing ctrl-D to end input.

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work on the python IDLE in case the OP is using that.

Comment: Use Ctrl+z to end input for windows

Answer (score 9):

You can easily create one, using generators. Here is one such implementation. Note you can either press a blank return or any Keyboard Interrupt to break out of the inputloop

```
>>> def multi_input():
    try:
        while True:
            data=raw_input()
            if not data: break
            yield data
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return


>>> userInput = list(multi_input())
359716482
867345912
413928675
398574126

>>> userInput
['359716482', '867345912', '413928675', '398574126']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Each `input()` will only accept a single line. Strategies around this:

- You can repeatedly call `input()` in a loop until it receives a blank line
- You can repeatedly call `input()` in a loop until the user does ctrl-D on a UNIX-like OS, at which point EOFError will be raised which you can catch
- Read the data from a text file or other more appropriate source than stdin

Comment: And switch to raw_input() instead

Comment: Using `print` as a function, so probably Py3.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi there,**

You could try this approach I made based on your request. I put some comments on the code to explain what I was trying to achieve. Glad to have the opportunity to get into some python code, I am new to this language but I totally love it!

```
def multi_input():
    try:
        #This list will hold all inputs made during the loop
        lst_words = []
        # We will store the final string results on this variable
        final_str ='' 
        #Let's ask first the user to enter the amount of fruits
        print("Please Type in your List of Fruits. \n Press << Enter >> to finish the list:")
        
        #Loop to get as many words as needed in that list
        while True:
            #Capture each word o'er here, pals!
            wrd = input()
            # If word is empty, meaning user hit ENTER, let's break this routine
            if not wrd: break
            # if not, we keep adding this input to the current list of fruits
            else:
                lst_words.append(wrd)

#What if ther user press the interruption shortcut? ctrl+D or Linus or MacOS equivalent?
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("program was manually terminated by the user.")
        return
#the time has come for us to display the results on the screen
    finally:
        #If the list has at least one element, let us print it on the screen
        if(len(lst_words)>0):
            #Before printing this list, let's create the final string based on the elements of the list
            final_str = '\n'.join(lst_words)
            print('You entered the below fruits:')
            print(final_str)
        else:
            quit
#let us test this function now! Happy python coding, folks!
multi_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using python file handling:

```
userInput = []
with open("example.txt", "r") as f :
    for x in f :
        userInput.append(x)
```

However, in this case you need to provide your input as a text file (example.txt).

Answer (score -2):

```
lines = []
while True:
s =input("Enter the string or press ENTER for Output: ")
if s:
    lines.append(s)
else:
    break;

print("OUTPUT: ")
for i in lines:
print (i)

Input:
359716482
867345912
413928675
398574126
546281739
172639548
984163257
621857394
735492861

Output:
359716482
867345912
413928675
398574126
546281739
172639548
984163257
621857394
735492861
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: All the input can be given at once by pasting directly to get the output shown.