# Python raw_input, input and other multi-line methods fail to read std input

Tags: python, input, freeze

I"m trying to store 2 multi line inputs in 2 variables. However, std input methods keep getting hung up. I cannot change input format, but I can always expect 2 strings will be provided together. There is a new line character at the end of the first block and a new line character at the end of the second block.

I have tried several solutions from previous posts on how to accept multi line input, but none work for this case:
[Store multi-line input into a String (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426699/store-multi-line-input-into-a-string-python/10426764)

When I try to use this code:
y input is accepted but x input is never accepted. I think the compiler is misinterpreting a line break somehow.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

```
y = input().strip()
x = input().strip()
```

```
TGGGAGGAGCAGTGATAATGCTACCTTGCTCGTGCCCCTTTAATGCCGGTGTCATCGCCTTAATGGGGTTCACAAGCAGTTACGGGGGGTCAAGTAATCATCGCGTTCGTCTTAGACGTGTCAGAGAACTAGTTTTGGAATCATTAACGACCTGCAATACTAGGTGCCAGCATAGGGTCTTTCGGAAGCACAACGTTGGAAGGCATCGCTTAGTGTAACCTAGTTACGGGAAGGCTACAGGTGCGGATGGTGGGGCCCAGCTGGGACTCAATCCAGGGACATCGGACTTTCGTTGGGGTTGAGCGGTCGCGAGGATTCGCAAGAGGGCGCCTTACAATGTTACCGTTTAGATTTACGGCCATTCCGACTTTGCAATTATTACCTTGAGCGATGCCGGCCATGCCGCGACATTATCAGTGATGTGTTCTCTCTCGGCTTGGTCGTTCAAACACGGGGCGTCATAGCTGAGTAGCCAAGGCAAACCAATTACCTACGTTCTGACCTGGCTGAATCTTGTGGAGCACCGGATCCAAGCAGTCGTGCCGGAGATTGTAGGCCAGCTTGTCATTCTGGATTGCGTTCCGCCCGATGTGAGCTTGTTCATACACCGAGTACGGGCTGCATTGGATCGTTCTATACGACAACGCTTCAGATCTCGAGTGCGTGGATCGAAGAAAGCGGAAGTCCGTTCGCGGACGCTCACAGCTGGTTGCTGCCGGCACCAACATGAACCGATCACCTAGCGCTTATAGTAAGCGGATATATCTTAGTATTAACCTTTCATTCCGGGCGGCACCTGAATGGGCAGTCTCGATTGATTAAGATCCCTTACTCTTCGAACTCGCGCGGACACGTCGTGCGCATCAATGGCAGTTATCTCGTATTAATACATACGCGTGATCAGCGCTATAGGGTATTTTTAGTTTTGGTCAACTCCGCAGTCACTGTGGATTGAATTGAGCATGCGGGCGAAGATCTGCTTTTCATCGCCTCTAACCAA
TATGGAGGACCAATGGTAGATGATACCGTTGCTCGGGGCGCTTTAAAGCCGGAGTAATGCGCCTATGAATGTGGGTTCACAGAGGAGTTCCCGGGGGGTCAACATCATCATGCGAGTGTCGTCTTAAAAGTGGCAGAATAACTGGTTTCTATGTATATCATTGAGCACCATCAATACGAGGTGTCAGCATGAGGCTCGTTCGGATGCCCGGCCTTGGAAGGCATCTGAGTTAGTATAACACTAGTTACGCGAAGGCTACAGGTGCGTGATCGTGCGGCCCAGTTGGGACTCAATTGAGGGACACGCGGACTTTCGTCGGGCTGTCAGAGGCCGGTCGGGGGAATGCGCAGGTTGTGCGGCACATACAATGTTATCGTTTCAGAATTTTATCGGCCATATCCGACTTTGCAATTATATTCCTTGCAGCGATGCCGGGGGAGCCGCGTACATGCATCAGTGTATGTATGCTCACTCGGCTATGTCGGTTCATAACCTGGCGCATATTAGCTGAGTAGACAAGGACTAAACCAATTAAACTACGTTCTGACCTCGCTATAGTATGTGAGTGAGTCACCGGATCCGAGCAGTTCGGGCCGCAGATTGGAGGCCAGCTTGTCATACTGGGTTGACCGTTTCGCCCGATGGGAGCTTGGTATCATACATCGAGTTACGTGGCTGCATTGTGTATCGTTCTGTTACGTACAACGCCTTCAAGGTCCCGAGTGCGAGGGTTCCCAGAAAAGCTGGAAGCGCAGTTCGTGAACTGCTCACAGCTGGTGGCTGCCGGCACCAACATGCACTTCGACTCACCTACCCAGCTAAATGTAAGCGCATATCTCTTAGTATATAACCTTTACATATCCGGGCGACGTACAGTAAAGAAGCAGGCTCGATGTCGTAGAGTTACCCTTACTACACTCGCAAATCGCGCGGACACGGTATGTACGCATTGAATCGACAGTTCTCTCGTATTTAGTACATACGCGTGATCAGCTGCTATAGAGTAATTCTAGCTTTGAGTGAACACCTCAGTGATGGCTGGATTGTAACTGAGCAACGCGGTCTGAGCGAACGGTTTTTGCATCGCGCTCTAACCAGG
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [taking multiline input with sys.stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692149/taking-multiline-input-with-sys-stdin)

Comment: If you have a solution then post an answer and mark it as correct in 2 days, do not edit the question to point it out.

Comment: Got it will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was IDE specific. VS Code cannot accept large string input from console. No problems when using PyCharm.