# is there a way where i copy and paste a company address in python input and it prints as multiple line output?

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, multilinestring, docxtpl

I'm trying to copy & paste a company address into a python script to automate my cover letter. when I paste the address it shows up in a single line in the created word document. I want it to be in the number of lines as I copied it.

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import datetime
import sys

company_name = input("Enter name of the Company : ") 

position_name = input("Enter name of the Position: ")

hiring_person = input("Enter name of the Hiring Person: ")

company_address = input("Enter the company address: ").splitlines()

today_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

context = {'today_date': today_date, 
           'company_name' : company_name, 
           'hiring_person' : hiring_person,
           'position_name' : position_name,
           'company_address' : company_address}

doc = DocxTemplate("master_cover_letter.docx")
doc.render(context)
doc.save('Cover_letter_'+company_name+'_'+position_name+'.docx')
```

**This is what I had in the "master_cover_letter.docx"**

{{today_date}}

{{hiring_person}}

{{company_address}}

Re: Job Application - {{position_name}}

Dear {{hiring_person}},

I am writing to express my interest in the position of {{position_name}}. Having in-depth knowledge in a wide range of relevant technologies and etc.

consider the following as the company address which is in 4 lines.

Tesla Automation GmbH,

Rudolf-Diesel-Strasse 14,

54595 Prüm,

Germany.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store multi-line input into a String (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426699/store-multi-line-input-into-a-string-python)

Comment: @JanWilamowski not really. the output still came as a single line output. 
i used the following code instead. i just made sure the address i copy has a delimiter at the end of the line.
`company_address = input("Enter the company address: ").replace(',',',\n')`

Comment: Have you read the answers to the question I linked? Do no use `input()` because it will only accept a single line. Use one of the other suggestions made there.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Thanks. I did understand it. I use jupyter notebook and it returns a blank and I couldn't key in anything after running the line when I use `sys.stdin.readlines()`. would appreciate a find? Ty.

Comment: I'm not sure if stdin works in Jupyter. You could try reading in a text file instead.

Comment: Did you figure this out? One idea would be to breakup the `company_address` variable into multiple variables with their own prompts, e.g. `company_street_number`, `company_street_name`, `company_city`, etc